# SQL CASE with multiple join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a sql select code as below. I am trying to fetch the `trans_date` which will either be in `asutrans` or `asuhistr`. But the below code doesnt give me any value and nor does it fail.

Do you think we can use CASE statement like that?

```sql
SELECT 
    v.voucher_no,
    CASE
        WHEN t.voucher_no = v.voucher_no THEN t.trans_date
        ELSE t1.trans_date
    END AS valuedate
FROM
    aipdethis v
    JOIN asutrans t ON t.client = v.client and t.voucher_no = v.voucher_no
    JOIN asuhistr t1 ON  t1.client = v.client  and t1.voucher_no = v.voucher_no
WHERE
    v.voucher_no ='22094200'
```

If I run the codes separately, then it does give me the result from asihistr. As below-

```sql
SELECT
    v.voucher_no, t1.trans_Date FROM  aipdethis v
    JOIN asuhistr t1 ON t1.client = v.client and t1.voucher_no = v.voucher_no
WHERE
    v.voucher_no ='22094200'
```

Comment: Can you post the code which is working as well as which is not working. And also please tag the database you are using

Comment: just edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have case statement which checks voucher_no because you are already joining in the join query. I think this is what you're expecting:

```
select 
    v.voucher_no,
    CASE
         WHEN t.trans_date is null then t1.trans_date
         ELSE t.trans_date
    END AS valuedate
    
   FROM  aipdethis v
   JOIN  asutrans t ON  t.client = v.client and t.voucher_no = v.voucher_no
   JOIN asuhistr t1 ON  t1.client = v.client  and t1.voucher_no = v.voucher_no
  where v.voucher_no ='22094200';
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. I tried this as well. In my example, I know that the voucher_no '22094200' is not there in asutrans but is there in asuhistr. Even then its, not returning anything with the code you have suggested.

Comment: If you don't have that voucher_no, you will not get the results because you are using inner join

Comment: but that voucher_no is there in asuhistr from which trans_date should have been picked. In the real cases, the voucher_no can be in either of the table and we need to pick the corresponding trans_Date

Comment: Jim- thanks so much. This is now sorted. instead of t.trans_Date is null I used t.voucher_no is null